# Rails : Why nil object in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created a very simple Rails 3.1 app with basic stuffs like following:

My **PostsController.rb** has `new`, `index`, `create` methods:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all

    render :index
end
def new
   @post = Post.new
   render :new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
      render :index

    else
      render :new

    end

  end
```

The **new.html.erb** form:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages%>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address, :size=>60 %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

the index view (**index.html.erb**):

```
<table>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

my **routes.rb** has defined:

```
resources :posts
root :to => 'post#new'
```

With all above, when the new form is submited, the `create` method in **PostController** will be invoked, then inside the `create` method, if the new post is saved successfully, it will `render :index`,that's to render the **index.html.erb** view, things are fine at this point. but I got a error now in **index.html.erb** view:

It complains that the **@posts** in `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` is **nil**, why???

**-------------I also tried-------------------------**

I tried to use `redirect_to posts_path` in `create` method, then I got **undefined method `posts_path_url'** error

I also tried to use `redirect_to :index` in `create` method, then I got **undefined method `index_url'** error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because `@posts` variable is not set in your `Post#create` method as it is in `Post#index`. You have to remember that rendering a view doesn't call appropriate controller method.

You want to use `redirect_to` instead of `render`:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
        redirect_to :posts
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but please check my post, I have tried to use redirect_to :index also, but there is a new error message which complains "undefined method `index_url'", how to get rid of this then?

Comment: @Leem.fin sorry, my mistake, it should be `redirect_to posts_path`

Comment: Thank you but I still get an error "undefined method `posts_path_url'"

Comment: @Leem.fin I've just noticed that you've got `resources :post` in your routes.rb. Try changing that to `resources :posts`.

Comment: @Leem.fin You'll probably also want to change `root :to => 'post#new'` to `root :to => 'posts#new'`

Comment: @ maro ,Yes, thank you. And I get rid of the problem by using redirect_to :posts instead of redirect_to :posts_path

Comment: @Leem.fin Yeah, I was just going to write about ':posts' instead of 'posts_path'. The 'posts_path' thing is a view helper method so it's supposed to be used in views not controllers. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because a call to render does not invoke the index method on the controller, it only resolves the path to the view and renders it.

If you want @posts to be present you must set it yourself in your create action.

This works well with the default new and create methods (scaffold generated) because in both actions you set up the same instance variable @post. Only in the create action if the validation fails you can instantly reuse the @post instance variable that has different errors stored on it  and render the new view template to show the post form with errors.

If you want to redirect to the posts action you should use:

```
redirect_to posts_path
```

Comment: But isn't the  @posts = Post.all should be inside index method? (you said in create method), If I want to set it in index method, what should be changed ?

Comment: I think I misread your question, I thought you wanted to have the unsaved object with the errors in your create action. You should use redirect_to as maro suggested.